# The Sheikh dies

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

The Sheikh dies, leaving behind three sons, 17 camels and the following order:

- His oldest son shall inherit one in two camels.
- His middle son shall inherit one in three camels.
- His youngest son shall inherit one in nine camels.

Now the three don't know what to do. So they ask an old friend of the family, which knows a solution such that everyone is happy.

What did he propose?

Comment: This was the example with which we were taught about catalyst (in Chemistry) in school :)

Comment: why sheikh.....

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Who else would own so many Camels?

Comment: He offers to chop the camels in half, and then gives all the camels to the one who implores him not to kill the camels and give them all to his brothers?

Comment: @JackM I'm trying to think where I heard that story (or something like it) before, can you remind me?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_of_Solomon

Comment: It's interesting to note that he leaves to his sons 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/9 = 17/18 of his assets.  Nobody knows who is supposed to inherit the missing 1/18...

Comment: Historically, when was the riddle first posed? Is there a version of this riddle recorded during the Renaissance? The Middle Ages?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> He brought an extra camel to assist in the division.
>
> Current total = $18$.
> Oldest son gets = $18/2 = 9$
> Middle son gets = $18/3 = 6$
> Youngest son gets = $18/9 = 2$
> Total camel involved = $9+6+2 = 17$.  
> The old friend then takes back the remaining extra camel and solves the problem.

Comment: Was this answer sarcastic? Please say it was :) I love it!

Comment: Nope, this is actually the genuine solution in all formulations of the problem.

Comment: @SiliconMind a sarcastic answer might be, he killed all three sons and took the camels for himself, making them all happy (["Call no man happy before his death"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D32) -- Solon of Athens).

Comment: are you saying 17=18 ????   according to your answer, 9/17 = 1/12 .

Comment: Wait a minute!  That adds up, but not really!  Something fishy is happening with these camels!

Comment: @bgmCoder Plot twist: all the camels are actually fish.

Comment: @randal'thor haha - humpback whales

Comment: @bgmCoder Nothing fishy is happening with the camels. It's the ratios in the will that are fishy. See [yoniLavi's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2626/6144).

Answer (score 104):

Note that the mathematical inconvenience is caused by the fractions in the will not summing to one:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} = \frac{17}{18}$$

Assuming that the father intended to divide the entire flock, we can

> normalize the fractions using division by 17/18, to get the expected solution.

- The eldest son will get:

  > $$ \frac{1}{2} \div \frac{17}{18} \times 17\ \textrm{Camels} = 9\ \textrm{Camels} $$
- The middle son will get:

  > $$ \frac{1}{3} \div \frac{17}{18} \times 17\ \textrm{Camels} = 6\ \textrm{Camels} $$
- The youngest son will get:

  > $$ \frac{1}{9} \div \frac{17}{18} \times 17\ \textrm{Camels} = 2\ \textrm{Camels} $$

Comment: In the traditional solution, this is done by the wise man coming along and giving them his camel.

Comment: @JoeZ. But this seems a lot simpler to understand. The wise man trick fails mathematically in other situations even though it may look just as logical.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code It _does_ work mathematically in every situation, just you need to figure out how many to add. It's basically just reverse-engineering this.

Answer (score 65):

C = Camel.

First son gets

> **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** C **C** = 9 camels.

Second gets

> **C** C C **C** C C **C** C C **C** C C **C** C C **C** C = 6 camels.

Third gets

> **C** C C C C C C C C **C** C C C C C C C = 2 camels.

Total number of camels is 17. No need for an extra camel.

Comment: However, in the first case, for example, the first son is getting 9/17 of all the camels, not 1/2 of them.

Comment: The first gets 9/17, > 1/2, the second gets 6/17 > 1/3, and third gets 2/17 > 1/9. They all get more than their fair shares of 17.

Comment: I interpreted "one in two", "one in three", and "one in nine" to mean exactly this.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but `C = Camel` :)

Comment: This solution looks right, but doesn't work if you would actually do it. <br/>
You can see the first C is marked for the first, second and third son. So who gets it after all?<br> 
If you would do this, it's more like:<br> 
C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C<br>
<br>
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   <br>
    2     2?    2     2?    2     <br>
                3?                <br>
<br>
So this is from where the confusion comes: according to the algorithm, some camels have multiple owners, while others have none.

Comment: @Flax one should assume that some communication between the brothers exists that solves that particular problem. In any case, my aim was not to actually "solve" the problem, it was to show that one can solve it in another way than the usual.

Comment: @Flax Since C=C, one can substitute a different camel at any point and maintain (in)equality.

Comment: @Flax, it is correct that the first camel is tagged by all sons. But the process could look like this. 1st son tags every second camel. 2nd every third and the last one every ninth. Then some camels will have 1, 2 or 3 tags and some camel will have none. So when the 1st son takes a camel with his tag on it, and sees his bros tags he simply moves the tags of his bro to an untagged camel. So he will get his 9 camels. The 2nd son looks for a camel with his tag on it, and if the 3rd sons tag is also on that camel he moves it to an untagged camel. Gets his 6 camels. 2 camels left for bro number 3.

Answer (score 15):

This is how I see it. The father being a knowledgeable man, knows that he has three pregnant camels.

So at the time of his death he says that the oldest would receive one in two, or one camel, a pregnant camel, which implies a third camel carried by the mother camel. Thus the oldest receives three camels.

The same goes for the middle who receives one in three camels. He will get two camels who are not pregnant and one that is. Thus, with time, he will receive four.

Finally the youngest will receive eight not pregnant camels, and one that is. Thus he will receive ten camels.

3+4+10=17.

The point would be that all three sons will have at least one fertile camel (the other camels may be infertile). The old friend is brought in to distinguish each pregnant camel and to allot one to each son.

No extra camels.

Comment: But this requires that initially they have only 14 (visible) camels. I don't think when a statement says "XYZ dies and leaves behind 17 camels" it actually means 14 camels with 3 of them pregnant.

Answer (score 6):

The **old** friend knows Sheikh and their son from long time ago...

He knew that the sons were not happy to work with each other and always complain and threat that they want to be separate. This makes the Sheikh very sad !

So Sheikh decided to create an impossible puzzle, not only to convince the sons to be with each other, but also show them that there are many cases that being together is the best solution.

So the old friend knows the solution:

> None of you can inherit any thing, you must be together and share the camels.

Comment: the tradional solution to such a conundrum is fratricide.

Answer (score 5):

There are other correct answers up there, but this puzzle is improved if instead of $18-1=17$ camels is available, there are $2*18-1=35$ camels available.

Then when the old friend brings a camel to make the division work, eldest gets $36/2=18$, middle gets $36/3=12$, youngest gets $36/9=4$ camels, which sums to 34, leaving TWO surplus camels, so the old friend gets his camel back, and claims the other as his reward for solving the brothers' problem.

[edit] I delivered a version of the traditional puzzle to an extracurricular math club for 6th-7th graders this week, and they loved it. I staged it "One day in Arabia, a mathematician was traveling on his camel through the desert, when he came across three men and a pack of camels. They were crying, and sharpening knives..."

After the class was done, I was thinking, wouldn't it be cooler if instead of just getting his camel back, he actually got a bonus camel? And (near)doubling the herd was able to double the slop from those fractions not summing to 1. I'm going to ask them next week, "What if there were 35 camels?" and let them work it out.

Comment: You can't just change the rules of the question like that.

Comment: It's not a rule change, it's an improvement. Will definitely try to remember.

Comment: Thanks. I delivered a version of the traditional puzzle to an extracurricular math club for 6th-7th graders this morning, and they loved it. I staged it "One day in arabia, a mathematician was traveling on his camel through the desert, when he came across three men and a pack of camels. They were crying, and sharpening knives..."

Answer (score 4):

The point is that each brother is "happy" because each one ends up with at least as much as he was promised in the will. We do not in fact give the eldest brother $\frac{17}2$ camels, we give him $\lceil\frac{17}2\rceil$. But the question only requires that he be "happy", not that he get exactly the right amount. It just so happens that $\lceil\frac{17}2\rceil+\lceil\frac{17}3\rceil+\lceil\frac{17}9\rceil=17$. In other words, the father left them less than 100% of his camels in the will, which is why there was wriggle room to give them all what they wanted while giving the family friend a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

I number camels like below and group them as `two / three / nine` to select `one` in each group:

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
      +---+---+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+---.
two   |   |   |   |   |    |     |     |     |
      +---+-+-+---+---+-+--+-----+-----+--+--+---.
three |     |     |     |        |        |  
      +-----+-----+-----+--------+--------+------.
nine  |                 |                 
      +-----------------+------------------------.
```

That last groups not completed, I can select that wanted one camel in two ways:

1. First camel

   ```
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
         +---+---+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+---.
   two   |*  |*  |*  |*  |*   | *   | *   | *   | *      => 9 Camels
         +---+-+-+---+---+-+--+-----+-----+--+--+---.
   three |- * -|* -  |- * -| *  -   | -  *  -| *  -      => 6 Camels
         +-----+-----+-----+--------+--------+------.
   nine  |- - - - - * - - -| -  -  *  -  -  -  -  -      => 2 Camels
         +-----------------+------------------------.
   ```
2. Last camel

   ```
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ..
         +---+---+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+---..
   two   |  *|  *|  *|  *|   *|    *|    *|    *|    *   => 8 Camels + 1  out-bounded Camel 
         +---+-+-+---+---+-+--+-----+-----+--+--+---..
   three |  - *|- * -|  - *| -  *  -|    -  *| -  *  -   => 6 Camels
         +-----+-----+-----+--------+--------+------..
   nine  |  - - - - - * - -| -  -  -  *  -  -  -  -  -   => 2 Camels
         +-----------------+------------------------..
   ```

   And `Camel 1` is not selected so replace it with that out-bounded camel.

And at last `one in two` selects 9 camels, `one in three` selects 6 camels and `one in nine` selects 2 camels.

[image: An extra image to make more sense]