# I apologise in advance for this

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

A man has 17 cigarettes.

He gives half of the cigarettes to his oldest son.

He gives one third of the cigarettes to his middle son.

He gives one ninth of the cigarettes to his youngest son.

**Question:**

> What brand are they?

Comment: I was *this close* to closing this as a dup . . .

Comment: Why is the actual question in spoiler tags?

Comment: @BrianJ: I assume its because  this question is something of a joke and it is, in a way, hiding the punchline.

Comment: I actually love this. I'm one for very small petty humor.

Comment: Is the title part of the riddle? Because otherwise it's a horrible title. But knowing the answer, I don't understand how it's related.

Comment: The question is (or was) in spoiler tags because: 1. for the reason BrianJ suggests, it is as much joke as puzzle, and therefore: 2. we want to give the reader time to leap to the wrong conclusion before they see what the question is. The title is what it is: 1. partly to twig the reader not to expect the expected; and 2. as a genuine apology in advance for something that is as much a joke as it is a puzzle; and 3. click bait.

Comment: Clearly not a very good brand, considering he's given away most of what he had.

Comment: Don't know about the brand, but they might be double-jointed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Perhaps they are:

> Camel brand cigarettes.

Because.

> This puzzle is usually posed with camels instead of cigarettes; see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/the-sheikh-dies) for example.

Comment: You get my +1, that's a nice answer!

Answer (score 85):

A different possibility:

> 17 is the brand, not the number of cigarettes.  Assuming, of course, that the answer doesn't need to be a real brand.

Comment: I like this. +1

Comment: Particularly since "17" is not divisible by 2, 3, and 9.

Comment: Seems that there is or was a brand by almost that name. http://www.cigarettespedia.com/index.php/BrandSahara_17, http://www.cigarettespedia.com/index.php/Sahara_17_KS-12-S_-_Indonesia

Answer (score 42):

> [Sterling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_(cigarette)), which is kind of infamous for sometimes having only 17 cigarettes in their packs ([ref1](https://www.aspokesmansaid.com/complaint/566806a676f7bc0a50000035), [ref2](https://www.complaintboard.com/sterling-cigarettes-l503/page/2)).

Comment: Ooh, this one's clever. I've never heard of this (probably because I don't smoke) but it's a fascinating answer

Answer (score 20):

> This is an old puzzle, but it’s usually asked about camels, not cigarettes. The brand, therefore, is clearly Camel.

Comment: Oof… 52 seconds behind the leading answer, for a score difference of (currently) +26 to +7.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine - Meh. Had fun answering it; I like the rep, but I don't play _because_ of it. It's all about the mental stimulation for me.

Answer (score 14):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but

> Chocolate Cigarettes! So he can actually do the fractions properly
>  without destroying the cigarettes.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first [badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges)?

Comment: @boboquack Second badge. First badge will be for posting an answer. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 Ahaha but I made the comment before the answer was up-voted ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also here is the explanation for those who are interested:

> 1/2+1/3+1/9 = 9/18+6/18+2/18 = 17/18 so the old man would give 9 to his
>  oldest son, 6 to his middle one and 2 to the youngest. 17 in total. 18
>  is the common denominator between 2, 3 and 9. This way you can
>  divide things that cannot be divided, such as cigarettes or...
>  camels. Apparently it is a famous riddle with camels instead of
>  cigarettes, hence the joke. The trap is that we tend to think in
>  decimals when it comes to dividing non-multiples and so at first it appears to be an
>  impossible problem to solve.

What I especially like here, intended or not, is that the spoiler cartridge looks like a cigarette:

> Camel

Comment: It *is* impossible to solve. The "solution" is fallacious. It only works if you reinterpret the bequests as permitting normalization. I don't know what you think decimals have to do with it.

Comment: Nothing in the problem prevents you to do just that @Acccumulation It is the puzzling stack exchange not the math one ;)